# How to bond end of row and start of line while reading from txt?

Tags: python

I have a txt like this and I read this from a txt file.

```
that's mai purpose! in order not to.
go and.. ll' be in h'van,.
```

I want to create a list like this : `["that's","mai","purpose!","in","order","not","to.\ngo","and..","ll'","be","in","h'van,."]`

I tried to `split()` but it works until the `\n` part how can i deal with it ? Difficult part is "`to.\ngo`" Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of saying "I tried split()", you should edit your question to show the exact code you tried. You should also show the output you actually get and explain how it differs from what you want.

Comment: `split()` works on whatever characters you tell it to use. If you only split on spaces, it shouldn't split on newlines.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're reading the file one line at a time, instead of reading the whole thing into a single string. But since you didn't post your code, there's no way to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `file.read()` to fetch all content as a single string and then call `str.split` to split the words as:

```
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    my_file_str = f.read()
    my_list = my_file_str.split(' ')
    #         split on space ' ' ^
```

Comment: This does not address the issue with the new line character.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It does.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Are you sure? `.split(' ')`?

Comment: How does the output from your code differ from the output posted by the OP?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye How?

Comment: That says *"I want to create a list like this"* <---expected result, NOT the current result

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri doh! That's what I get for skimming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("c.txt") as f:
     lines = f.read()
     mlist = lines.strip().split(' ')
print mlist
```

Output:

```
["that's", 'mai', 'purpose!', 'in', 'order', 'not', 'to.\ngo', 'and..', "ll'", 'be', 'in', "h'van,."]
```

Comment: I think OP wants the newline character.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OP said I want to create a list like this : `[...'to.\ngo'...]`.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question since it lacks a MCVE.